# What Time Does My iTunes Gift Get Received To The Recipient?

Tags: itunes, email, gift

I've purchased my sister a gift from iTunes for tomorrow (29th Nov) and was wondering what time roughly would she receive it? - GMT

Answer (score 2):

I tried it before and receive it within minutes. Make sure she checks her email spam filters.